# WebRTC Packets in Network Logs

Tags: networking, udp, webrtc

Why is it that when WebRTC is streaming, nothing is captured in the network logs in the developers console in Chrome whereas when looking at Wireshark, it is clear that UDP segments are being transmitted and received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebRTC isn't wired up in chrome devtools. You'll see all peerconnections and (statistics about) their data transfer in chrome://webrtc-internals however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firefox WebRTC internals , `about:webrtc`